# Triggers en sql

Tags: sql, oracle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy empezando en triggers, tengo 2 tablas con los mismo campos, sobre información de empleados, y tengo que crear un trigger que se ejecute después de eliminar un registro.

Al eliminar un registro, se debe ir a la segunda tabla.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DIS_EMP_BORRAR
ON EMPLEADOS AFTER DELETE 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS_BAJA (DNI, NOMEMP, MNG, SALARIO, USUARIO, FECHA)
VALUES (EMPLEADOS.DNI, EMPLEADOS.NOMEMP, EMPLEADOS.MGR, EMPLEADOS.SALARIO, USER, SYSDATE)
COMMIT;
END;
```

Ese es el código que hice, pero me marca error en la línea 2, e ignora esa línea, estoy usando Oracle ApplicationExpress

Comment: Podés darle formato al código con el botón que indica `{}`. Además, dale un título más descriptivo a tu pregunta, para atraer más usuarios a ella. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Cambiar los paréntesis por llaves?, acabo de modificar el código, use :old. pero me marca error que esas referencias no son permitidas en triggers de nivel tabla :(

Comment: Edité tu pregunta para dar formato al código, por favor dale clic en [edit] y observa como se hace. Por otro lado, tanto código como errores se publican como texto, el pantallazo está de más si agregas la información del error.

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que buscas, puedes usar un trigger `for each row`, que se ejecuta una vez por cada fila que se elimine de la tabla.

En este trigger tendrás accesible el pseudo-registro `old`, con el que puedes acceder a los registros de la fila que e borró.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DIS_EMP_BORRAR
AFTER DELETE 
ON EMPLEADOS 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO EMPLEADOS_BAJA (DNI, NOMEMP, MNG, SALARIO, USUARIO, FECHA)
  VALUES (:OLD.DNI, :OLD.NOMEMP, :OLD.MGR, :OLD.SALARIO, USER, SYSDATE);
END;
/
```

Como puedes observar, he quitado la sentencia `COMMIT` del trigger, pues el control de transacciones pertenece a un nivel que está fuera de los triggers.

Dicho todo esto, Oracle tiene excelentes prestaciones de auditoría, si necesitas llevar un control de las acciones sobre los datos, te recomiendo investigar sobre las mismas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, después de haber investigado un poco encontré eso mismo sobre los old, y modifiqué mi código inicial, pero ahora con la ayuda que me diste me marca que la sentencia de la línea 3 no está propiamente finalizada, gracias de antemano

Comment: @AdriánRosario Le faltaba un punto y coma...